# OutOfMemoryException using BZip2 (SharpZipLib)

Tags: .net, stream, arrays, out-of-memory, sharpziplib

I use Asp.net , .net 3.5, win2003, iis 6.0.

I use Oracle for gathering files, saving file in SharpZipLib.BZip2 compressed format in field RAW in table Oracle.

My application is Web, and I use WCF Service for get data (array of bytes) of a file. The aspx page send file to user (download file).

My issue-problem:

I read DATA from Oracle, (I call to WCF Service). I get array of bytes (byte[]),

I try Uncompress file using SharpZipLib.BZip2

```
using (MemoryStream inData = new MemoryStream(data))
{ 
using (MemoryStream outData = new MemoryStream())
{
          BZip2.Decompress(inData, outData); //<==================== Fails here OutOfMemoryException
          return outData.ToArray();
}

}
```

the error is because the file "uncompressed" is big, very big (> 500 MB) !!!

compressed file: 4MB

uncompressed file: > 500 MB

I do test like this:

```
BufferedStream bufin = new BufferedStream(instream);

            using (MemoryStream outData = new MemoryStream())
            {
                BZip2.Decompress(bufin, outData);

                return outData.ToArray();
            }
```

But I get the same OutOfMemoryException

Trace Stack of Exception

```
   en System.IO.MemoryStream.set_Capacity(Int32 value)
   en System.IO.MemoryStream.EnsureCapacity(Int32 value)
   en System.IO.MemoryStream.WriteByte(Byte value)
   en Reale.Frk.Compression.BZip2.BZip2.Decompress(Stream inStream, Stream outStream)
```

Code of SharpZipLib.BZip2.Decompress

```
public static void Decompress(Stream inStream, Stream outStream) 

            {

                  if ( inStream == null ) {

                        throw new ArgumentNullException("inStream");

                  }

                  if ( outStream == null ) {

                        throw new ArgumentNullException("outStream");

                  }


                  using ( outStream ) {

                        using ( BZip2InputStream bzis = new BZip2InputStream(inStream) ) {

                             int ch = bzis.ReadByte();

                             while (ch != -1) {

                                   outStream.WriteByte((byte)ch);

                                   ch = bzis.ReadByte();

                             }

                        }

                  }

            }
```

any suggestions, comments, sample source code ?

Answer (score 2):

Skip the `MemoryStream` and write directly to a file.

Else add more memory to the server.

Another option to specify the initial capacity for the `MemoryStream`.

Comment: requeriments of app, I prefer avoid write to a file :(. Add more memory server is impossible.

Comment: Then you are f*cked. Try using a less memory-intensive decompression algorithm. If adding more memory is a problem, I suspect you have way bigger problems....

Comment: any other solution, please?

Comment: @Kiquenet: Use streamable compression. GZip is already built in.

Answer (score 0):

Chances are that you are getting out of memory error because the single contiguous memory area for the memory stream of 500 MB is not available on your system, but you may have enough non-contiguous memory blocks. Use [MemoryTributary](https://memorytributary.codeplex.com/) class instead and it might work. The class may require some tweaking (if I remember correctly it may not cleanly return the very last block and pad it with ASCII(0))